# how to run multiple defs () - Python MAYA?

Tags: python, function, constructor, maya

I am following a Python for Maya tutorial from: https://github.com/gyassa4/MayaPyth/blob/master/gear_builder.py
After I run the code it only run first def() which creates a Gear with teeth=10. However, it won't run the second def() which changes the number of gears' teeth as instructed in def changeTeeth(constructor, extrude, teeth=25, length=1).Do I need a Class to run multiple defs()?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def createGear(teeth=10, length=1):
    spans = teeth * 2
    transform, constructor = cmds.polyPipe(subdivisionsAxis=spans)
    sideFaces = range(spans * 2, spans * 3, 2)
    cmds.select(clear=True)
    for face in sideFaces:
        cmds.select('%s.f[%s]' % (transform, face), add = True)
        extrude = cmds.polyExtrudeFacet(localTranslateZ = length)[0]
    return transform, constructor, extrude

createGear()

def changeTeeth(constructor, extrude, teeth=25, length=1):
    spans = teeth * 3
    cmds.polyPipe(constructor, edit=True, subdivisionsAxis=spans)
    sideFaces = range(spans * 2, spans * 3, 5)
    faceNames = []
    for face in sideFaces:
        faceName = 'f[%s]' % (face)
        faceNames.append(faceName)
        cmds.setAttr('%s.inputComponents' % (extrude),
        len(faceNames),*faceNames,type="componentList")
        cmds.polyExtrudeFacet(contructor, extrude, edit=True, ltz=length)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
createGear()
```

this is running the first def

```
changeTeeth(constructor = "objname",
            extrude = "extrudename")
```

put this at the end will run the second one
Note that two of the arguments are mandatory as you have assigned default values to :

```
teeth=25, length=1
```